# youtube-dl not accepting playlist url

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

With this code

```
import os

with open('urls.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
            os.system("youtube-dl "+"--write-thumbnail "+"--skip-download "+"--yes-playlist " +line)
```

The first image in the playlist downloads, then I get an error message saying 'list' is not recognized as an internal or ex ternal command, operable program or batch file. In 'urls.txt' I have just one url of a Youtube playlist. The url is this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GA3St3Rf9Gs&list=PL-uc0GihCvU9s24BT_mvTzt3zm7e2uDGm

It's cutting off input after the & symbol. If I replace 'list' in the url with 'foo' I get the same message. What do I do to make youtube-dl accept playlist URL?

Comment: Try looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334081/downloading-multiple-files-with-youtube-dl). Also try updating the `youtube-dl`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has a major [command injection security vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection). You have triggered this (with harmless code) by accident. You are executing

```sh
youtube-dl --write-thumbnail --skip-download --yes-playlist \
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GA3St3Rf9Gs&list=PL-uc0GihCvU9s24BT_mvTzt3zm7e2uDGm
```

Since the ampersand is a [command character in shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line), you're running two commands

```
youtube-dl --write-thumbnail --skip-download --yes-playlist \
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GA3St3Rf9Gs
```

and

```
list=PL-uc0GihCvU9s24BT_mvTzt3zm7e2uDGm
```

Since there is no program with that name, the second command will likely fail.

To fix this, use proper subprocess invocations with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html):

```py
import subprocess

with open('urls.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        subprocess.check_call([
            "youtube-dl",
            "--write-thumbnail", "--skip-download", "--yes-playlist",
            line])
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to fix this,  quote the YouTube URL, as in:

```
yt-dlp --yes-playlist "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XArZ74galOE&list=PLDrswW4_QtejDZdLE4EOVXunQvqU18sPK"
```

Solved the problem.

<sub>Thanks to [nav3916872](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3916872/nav3916872)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `youtube_dl` library directly in your script and pass the urls to download from.

```
import os
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'writethumbnail': True,
    'skip_download': True,
    'noplaylist': False
}


with open('urls.txt') as f:
    sources = f.readlines()

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:    
    ydl.download(sources)
```

Answer (score 0):

in commandprompt , you just need to quote the url(with ampersand). You can try to escape the url(with ampersand) in the same way in python. Refer [youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#video-url-contains-an-ampersand-and-im-getting-some-strange-output-1-2839-or-v-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)